# The problem of null relationship in the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My problem is that the data sent to the interface model is null and I can not use my second table

```
  public ActionResult Create(PersonDetail personDetail1)
    {
```

PersonDetail is My Moudel and relationShip And that relationship is empty

```
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  What is the specific error that you are observing and what specific code produces that error?  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.